# Medir el tiempo inicial, Final y Total de un método en c#

Tags: c#

Tengo una duda respecto a como debo medir el tiempo de ejecución de determinado método  en c#, lo que he econtrado es que debo hacerlo con Stopwathch, mas o menos de esta forma:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
//mi código
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", sw.Elapsed.ToString)
```

Pero de esta forma solo obtengo un valor, El total. como podría obtener el inicial y el final? dado que lo que me piden es que imprima el tiempo inicial, final y el total (final - incial).

Comment: En este caso específico, Stopwatch no te ayudará. Esa clase es más orientada a mediciones de rendimiento. Para obtener la fecha de inicio, de final y el total de tiempo transcurrido, deberás utilizar el método de Arturo.}

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar el método de C#

```
DateTime()   

var tiempo = new DateTime();

DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now; 
DateTime date2 = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime date3 = DateTime.Today;
```

Y con las variables ya podrías hacer las operaciones .por ejemplo.

```
using System;

public enum TimeComparison {    EarlierThan = -1,    TheSameAs = 0,   
LaterThan = 1 }

public class DateManipulation {    public static void Main()    {
    DateTime localTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime utcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

    Console.WriteLine("Difference between {0} and {1} time: {2}:{3} hours",
                       localTime.Kind.ToString(),
                       utcTime.Kind.ToString(),
                       (localTime - utcTime).Hours,
                       (localTime - utcTime).Minutes);
    Console.WriteLine("The {0} time is {1} the {2} time.",
                       localTime.Kind.ToString(),
                       Enum.GetName(typeof(TimeComparison), localTime.CompareTo(utcTime)),
                       utcTime.Kind.ToString());    } } // If run in the U.S. Pacific Standard Time zone, the example displays 
// the following output to the console: 
// Difference between Local and Utc time: -7:0 hours 
// The Local time is EarlierThan the Utc time.
```

Aquí el enlace a la doc oficial 
[en la página de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netcore-3.1)