# Obtener intervalo de horas entre una hora de inicio y una de fin

Tags: html, c#, mvc

Buen dia.

Necesito obtener las horas disponibles entre dos horas, una de inicio y una de fin, y luego separlas por hora. Ejemplo: Tengo la hora de inicio la cual es 8:00 y la hora de fin que sera 19:00.

Necesito de alguna manera separar el rango de horas de esta manera:

```
8:00 - 9:00
9:00 - 10:00
10:00 - 11:00
```

Asi hasta llegar a la hora de fin.

Muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de ver mi pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Falta algo de información en tu pregunta. Cuando dices que necesitas separarlas por horas, a que te refieres? Necesitas un diccionario, una cadena de strings, que es exactamente lo que necesitas? Por otro lado, has intentado algo que podamos ver?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Medir el tiempo inicial, Final y Total de un método en c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/354691/medir-el-tiempo-inicial-final-y-total-de-un-m%c3%a9todo-en-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public List<string> GeneraIntervaloHoras(DateTime _horainicio, DateTime _horafin)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        //itera desde fecha inicio hasta fecha fin
        DateTime _horaactual = _horainicio;

        while (_horaactual < _horafin)
        {
            result.Add(
                _horaactual.ToShortTimeString() + " - " +
                _horaactual.AddHours(1).ToShortTimeString());

            _horaactual = _horaactual.AddHours(1);
        }

        return result;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GeneraIntervaloHoras_10elementos()
    {
        DateTime dtInicio = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dtFin = DateTime.Now.AddHours(9);

        var res = _csharpfunctions.GeneraIntervaloHoras(dtInicio, dtFin);

        Assert.IsTrue(res.Count == 10);
    }
```

Comment: Aunque tu respuesta me parece acertada, te recomiendo para el futuro esperar a que el autor de la pregunta clarifique la misma (por ejemplo, tal vez no necesite una lista de cadenas, sino separar en grupos una lista de fechas con lo que tu solución no sería adecuada) y tambien que demuestre algún intento por su parte de resolver el problema ( de esta manera se puede apreciar si ya ha intentado algo similar a lo que propones y no le sirve, o por ejemplo si es un ejercicio escolar es mejor que sea el mismo el que pueda resolverlo). Gracias de todas maneras por aportar

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apreciación, Pikoh. Apenas llevo un par de días que he decidido hacer aportaciones y le voy cogiendo el truco poco a poco. Sinceramente, con el enunciado de la pregunta no me quedó de entrada ninguna duda de lo que estaba pidiendo y creo que lo que le he contestado, es lo que pregunta. Si lo necesita en uno u otro formato ya él se arreglará para adaptarlo, pero la idea es claramente esa. El tema de que pudiera tratarse de un ejercicio escolar, pues ni se me había ocurrido. Es un punto a tener en cuenta!! gracias de nuevo

Comment: Gracias a ti por aceptar mis comentarios de tal buena forma! Lógicamente tenemos en cuenta a los nuevos usuarios y tratamos de ir poco a poco enseñándoles cual es el funcionamiento habitual del sitio, de ahi mi comentario. Gracias de nuevo por aportar y espero que lo sigas haciendo durante mucho tiempo.